# Rails change date format in form field attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Rails 4 with the rails-I18n gem.

Everything works fine except when i want to update an date field:
Inside the input field is the current date value in %Y-%m-%d format and i like to change the format to %d.%m.%Y

I have set the default date format in config/initializers/date_time_formats.rb

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%d.%m.%Y'

Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]= '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

The output in rails console is in my desired date format:

```
2.2.1 (main):0 > Date.tomorrow.to_s
=> "12.11.2015"
```

But after restarting the server the form field value is still in %Y-%m-%d.

[image]

```
  .form-group.row
    = f.label :valid_from, class: 'col-sm-2 form-control-label'
    .col-sm-4
      = f.date_field :valid_from, class: 'form-control', data: { provide: 'datepicker' }
      = errors_for @vat_class, :valid_from
```

How can i manage to have the input value-attribute format instead of %Y-%m-%d in %d.%m.%Y without using strftime in the view?

Comment: You're using a javascript plugin, what is it called, you'll need to do it in that I'd assume

Comment: even without javascript i get the default value in %Y-%m-%d instead of %d.%m.%Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can specify the input value explicitely, but it not the best solution i think, since you need to do this for every date field

```
= f.date_field :valid_from, class: 'form-control', data: { provide: 'datepicker' }, value: f.object.valid_from.to_s
```

Comment: Thanks Yury, i will stick to your solution!

Comment: @StandardNerd you're welcome! If i will find a better solution, i will post it here

Comment: That's great thanks! i was searching a long time for a clean solution.